# Unity problem with ordering and sorting layers

Tags: unity-game-engine, layer

I've some problems with Unity layers. Before was everything ok, now, I don't know why the game view show some elements behind. Has you can see in the image the red background in the game view isn't visible even if it has the same sorting layer has the text and its order in layer is fewer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, it would be helpfull if you would also share screenshots of the components you use, like SpriteRenderer...
Also, also, maybe show the layers you have configured.
Here is one setup for example:

**You can configure which sorting layers you want and in what order**
[image]

[image]

**After that in your Render Component of Choice you can set this layer and use the number (order in layer) for finer sorting**

Comment: As I wrote in the description of the problem I use both sorting and order layers. The problem is that before was everything all right and then suddenly changed without touching them. Canvas has foreground layer and order 0, such as the Game objects inside, and UI components have canvas render object so they have same order as canvas right? But as you can see in the last image I upload even if "Records" and "PlayerScore" has same layers they are shown differently

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved removing the sprite renderer for the background of the parent of the texts and I putted a separated sprite square for all the background with a order fewer